# Взаимодействие с 3D объектами в ВЕБе (WebGL, three.js)

Tags: three.js, webgl

Задача создать веб-страницу на которой будет некоторое количество 3D объектов и при нажатии на один из них должен менять свое положение (к примеру: имеется болт и насаженная на него гайка, и при нажатии на гайку она меняет свое положение тем самым "снимаясь" с болта).

Кто знает или читал статью с описанием алгоритма и есть-ли примеры подобной задачи?

Comment: А если сделать анимацию и при нажатии просто ее запускать?

Comment: Полагаю, что вы не знакомы с three.js. Потому что ваша задача элементарна. Попробуйте сначала разобрать несколько маломальский проектов на [официальном сайте](https://threejs.org//examples/). И [вот этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010281/move-objects-in-three-js) вопрос почитайте.

Comment: `THREE.Raycaster()` - для организации взаимодействия с объектами. `Tween.js` - для анимации; можно задавать сразу несколько анимаций для одного объекта, например, для гайки - вращение и перемещение. А вообще, неплохо бы сначала показать код. В англоязычном сегменте подобные вопросы типа "я ничего не сделал, расскажите как?" в лучшем случае просто минусуют.

Answer (score 0):

Если умеете работать с Blender, и нет жесткого ограничения использовать именно threejs, то можете попробовать blend4web, под задачу с вашим описанием в blend4web не придется писать ни строчки кода. А если возникнет необходимость усложнять проект, то использование javascript также возможно.